# MSBuild in AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I am trying a few tools by Atlassian and wanted to get the whole CI/CD working. So far, I am able to commit code in Visual Studio and have Bitbucket kick off a build request in Bamboo. However, my builds failed due to MSbuild not being in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin - makes sense as the VM does not have Visual Studio installed. What is the best practice to get this working. I know I can install VS on that VM and things should work, but what if I want to be able to terminate that VM and spin off a new one(with VS on it) whenever I need a new environment? Any ideas? Are there any "community" images one can use that would include this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old - but just in case someone else chances upon it; you don't need VS installed. Microsoft ships MSBuild as a standalone package (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760)...